# Append input field with converted characters as you type, JQUERY

Tags: jquery, keyup

This must be so easy but I am really stuck and cant work it out due to my poor jQuery skills.

The goal is to convert latin characters to capital greek characters as the user types in an input field.

It seems that I am pretty close, but my problem is that I get both my latin and greek characters together for a single keyup event. Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/harman79/dymtufy8/

HTML:

```
<input type="search" id="search-id">
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#search-id").bind('keyup', function(e) {
  var charMap = {
    65: 913,
    66: 914,
    67: 936,
    68: 916,
    69: 917,
    70: 934,
    71: 915,
    72: 919,
    73: 921,
    74: 926,
    75: 922,
    76: 923,
    77: 924,
    78: 925,
    79: 927,
    80: 928,
    81: 931,
    82: 929,
    83: 931,
    84: 932,
    85: 920,
    86: 937,
    87: 937,
    88: 935,
    89: 933,
    90: 918
  };

  $.each(charMap, function(index, value) {
    if (index == e.which) {
      $("#search-id").val(function(index, val) {
        return val + String.fromCharCode(value);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

If I replace `return val + String.fromCharCode(value);` with `return String.fromCharCode(value);` I only get my converted character but each new keyup replaces previous input contents.

Any hep would be much appreciated!
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
$("#search-id").bind('keyup', function(e) {
  var charMap = {
    65: 913,
    66: 914,
    67: 936,
    68: 916,
    69: 917,
    70: 934,
    71: 915,
    72: 919,
    73: 921,
    74: 926,
    75: 922,
    76: 923,
    77: 924,
    78: 925,
    79: 927,
    80: 928,
    81: 931,
    82: 929,
    83: 931,
    84: 932,
    85: 920,
    86: 937,
    87: 937,
    88: 935,
    89: 933,
    90: 918
  };

  $.each(charMap, function(index, value) {
    if (index == e.which) {
      $("#search-id").val(function(index, val) {
        // Remove last character and replace with new value
        return val.substring(0, val.length - 1) + String.fromCharCode(value);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="search-id">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!!! Got me unstuck. It seems that I will have to replace my keyup with keydown for faster conversion response but all logic is there now..

Comment: Yep, keydown would be the best bet for what you want.